# Timer - executar em hora definida

Tags: c#, services, timer

Estou desenvolvendo um Serviço do Windows, onde todo dia as 18:00 horas, preciso que seja disparado um evento.

Então estou utilizando a classe `Timer`.
Consegui disparar um evento, definindo a propriedade `Interval`, ou seja, a cada 120 segundos, por exemplo, e disparado o evento.

Porem, como faço para disparar o evento, as 18:00 horas?

Segue meu codigo:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = (1000)*(12); // 120  seconds 2 minutos
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();

        Enviar_Email.send_email_Start();
    }
```

Evento a ser disparado:

```
 public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        Send_Mail();
    }
```